# PHPMailer is not working at all

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to configure PHPMailer I've uploaded 1 file which is class.phpmailer.php and created another php file with this content:

```
<?php
require('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mypassword";
$mail->SetFrom("the same email address");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("the same email address");
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

and i get nothing at all not a success message nor a failure message. http://www.mawk3y.net/mailtest/test.php

Comment: Check logs. If logs are empty, check if logging is enabled in your php.ini

Comment: Add this to the beginning of your file to display all error messages: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Warning: require(PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/iy0xods5/public_html/mailtest/class.phpmailer.php on line 575

Warning: require(PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/iy0xods5/public_html/mailtest/class.phpmailer.php on line 575

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/iy0xods5/public_html/mailtest/class.phpmailer.php on line 575

but file is already there with the same name

Comment: PHPMailer requires the additional files. `class.phpmailer.php` does NOT contain all code. Check the installation manual for PHPMailer.

Comment: this file is already uploaded and I've uploaded this file right now PHPMailerAutoload.php and now I get this error : Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/iy0xods5/public_html/mailtest/class.phpmailer.php on line 1147

Comment: you need `class.smtp.php`

Comment: I just uploaded it class.smtp and I get this now : 2013-11-15 12:28:58 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: This means, it could not connect to GMail SMTP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41253/discussion-between-fracsi-and-jq-beginner)

Comment: I get this error with your link mat: 2013-11-15 12:34:27 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: gmail message to me : Someone recently used your password to try to sign in to your Google Account yasser.sharaf@gmail.com. This person was using an application such as an email client or mobile device. 

We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a hijacker trying to access your account. Please review the details of the sign-in attempt

Answer (score 4):

all answers are outdated now. Most current version (as of Feb 2018) does not have autoload anymore, and PHPMailer should be initialized as follows:

```
<?php

  include_once(FCPATH.'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
  include_once(FCPATH.'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php');
  include_once(FCPATH.'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php');

    $msj="My complete message";
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    //authentication SMTP enabled
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    //indico el puerto que usa Gmail 465 or 587
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = "xxxxxx";
    $mail->Password = "xxxx";
    $mail->SetFrom("xxxxxx@xxxxx.com","Name");
    $mail->AddReplyTo("xxx@xxx.com","Name Replay");
    $mail->Subject = "Test";
    $mail->MsgHTML($msj);
    $mail->AddAddress("xxxxxx@xxxxx.com");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
?>
```

Comment: @Juliana_Torres Great answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the require method.

You first have to extract all file of phpMailer repository.

instead of writing

```
require('class.phpmailer.php');
```

you need to include path where your PHPMailerAutoload.php file extracted.so you can replace it with.

```
require('path-of-extracted-folder/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

for more reference you can visit it's GitHub link

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem but I solved.This is the way I code

```
<?php 


require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
// Set PHPMailer to use the sendmail transport
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';              // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'abc@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'abc';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('abc1@gmail.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('abc@gmail.com', 'Shehan');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Test Mail';

$mail->Body = 'This is Test Mail';


//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
} 

?>
```